# Installshield LD - How to never overwrite config file in installing MSI upgrade

Tags: vbscript, windows-services, installshield, custom-action

I am creating an msi using installshield for installing a windows service. Whenever, I install an upgrade it replaces everything including the config file. I never want to replace the config file because every client has separate settings and they should remain intact. 
I googled a lot and some people say about options like check Never overwrite checkbox and set Permanent to true, but I did not find such options in installshield anywhere. I am not sure if they are talking about instlledshield or some other tool. I am also now trying to accomplish this using custom actions but facing errors.

I believe there must be some way to prevent installers from overwriting the config file.

Note: I am working in Visual Studio 2013 with Installshield Limited edition

I will highly appreciate any kind of help.

screenshot of installer
https://www.screencast.com/t/MtdlFGQG7

Comment: You need to put your configuration file into separate component. After set "Never overwrite" and "Permanent" properties for this component as needed.

Comment: Can you please explain how because I do not see any such options anywhere.

Comment: I am working in VS2013 though

Comment: Sorry, didn't notice you are using InstallShield Limited Edition. I cannot comment on this, as we are using pro version. Somebody else may help.

Comment: okay no problem.
I actually edited my question after your comments and mentioned Limited edition. I realized later. sorry. Thanks anyhow.

Answer (score 0):

Since your InstallShield is limited you'll have to manually set the attributes in your [Component table](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa368007%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396). Take a look at msidbComponentAttributesNeverOverwrite and possibly msidbComponentAttributesPermanent